# Property 'divElem' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor when using Template Reference Variable in V16

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have an div element in template and wanted to access the element by template reference variable.But i was facing the issue, it throws some error.

This is my div element
`<div (click)="settingUpItemsAnimations()" class="browse-shops-item" #browseShopItems></div>`

This is is how i was reading the that element in my component class
 `@ViewChild('browseShopItems', { read: ElementRef }) divElem: ElementRef;`

I was getting this error, don't know why this is not working in V16
**Property 'divElem' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
(property) Tab2Page.divElem: ElementRef**

i tried checking in V10 it was working but no idea why is it not working in V16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `divElem` is not defined in the constructor so the compiler will complain because of the `strictPropertyInitialization` rule.

You have 2 solutions.

- Make the property optional : `divElem?: ElementRef`
- Use the non-null assertion : `divElem!: ElementRef`